# Normal force at each support for a stick with two supports

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

This is a physics/mathematical modeling problem I gave myself and I got kind of stuck here trying to model it.  Imagine having some kind of stick or cane (don't assume uniform density) and supporting it with two fingers.  What is the contact force between each finger and the stick/cane/whatever.

Or, asked more mathematically:

Suppose we have a cylinder oriented with its bases facing the sides and with mass $m$.  The density at each given point defined by the function $\rho (x)$ or, perhaps more accurately, $\rho (x, y, z) = f(x)$, i.e. the density depends only on the horizontal position.  The cylinder is in a gravitational field defined by $\vec{g}(x,y,z) = -9.8 \hat k $ (i.e. uniform earth gravity at sea level) and is supported at two points $x_1$ and $x_2$.  There are no other forces acting on the cylinder, meaning $\sum \vec {F} = m\vec g + \vec{F}_{Nx_1} + \vec{F}_{Nx_2}=0$.  $\vec p = 0$.

I tried modelling this problem using torque, but the problem that I ran into was that the torque on the support for a force right above the support is zero, but I know experimentally that this would increase the force on that support.  Just to make sure I wasn't full of it, I actually tested this with a pen and my hand lol.

Comment: Please show your work with respect to torque.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two constraints:

- The sum of all forces on the cylinder are zero
- The sum of all torques on the cylinder are zero

You know that the sum of the supports will equal the weight, so one will be $x$ and the other will be $mg - x$.

Then calculate the torques on the cylinder from the supports.  There are several ways to do this, but the easiest is to find the center of mass and calculate the torque about that axis.  Then the weight distribution of the object can be ignored and you only need the distance from the center of mass to the supports.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The only thing that matters is the distance between the supports and the center of mass. This is because the net torque about the center of mass needs to be zero, so the supports closest to it are carrying most of the load.

Can you work out the details for? $$\sum \vec{M} = \sum \vec{r}_i \times \vec{F}_i =0 $$

<sub>Where $\vec{M}$ is the moment, $\vec{F}$ each load applied to the stick and $\vec{r}_i$ the position of each load *relative to the center of mass*.</sub>

Comment: I'm guessing M = torque?

Comment: Yes, torque, or moment of force. See edits above.

Answer (score 0):

All right, based on what everyone is telling me, here is my solution:

Let $\vec s \in \mathbb R^3$ be the position vector such that $\vec s = \vec 0$ at the center of mass of the stick and let $\vec s = x_1 \hat i$ be the position of one support and $\vec s = x_2 \hat i$ be the position of the other such that $x_1 < 0 < x_2$.

Because the stick as a whole has no linear motion:
$$\sum \vec F = 0$$
Because the stick as a whole has no rotational motion:
$$\sum \vec \tau = 0$$
Additionally, because the only forces acting on the stick are gravity and the contact force:
$$\sum \vec \tau = \vec \tau_g + \vec \tau_N=0$$
Assuming no air resistance, we know that the force of gravity functions as a linear force, therefore:
$$d\vec \tau_{ g}(\vec s) = \vec g\rho(\vec s)dV \times\vec s = \big[\vec g\rho(\vec s) \times\vec s\big] dV$$
Therefore, because we know that gravity would pull rigidly on the stick and assuming either no air resistance or uniform air resistance, integrating over the whole stick:
$$\sum \vec \tau_g = 0 = \iiint \big[\vec g\rho(\vec s) \times\vec s\big] dV $$
From this, we know that the superposition of the torque of the normal forces must be $\vec 0$.

Therefore:
$$\vec 0 = \vec \tau_{N(x_1)} +\vec \tau_{N(x_2)} = \vec F_{N(x_1)}\times x_1 + \vec F_{N(x_2)}\times x_2$$
AND
$$\vec F_{N(x_1)} + \vec F_{N(x_2)} = m\vec g$$
Moreover, because the normal forces are perpendicular to the center of mass and opposite the force of gravity:

$$ \vec F_{N(x_1)} \times x_1  + \vec F_{N(x_2)}\times x_2  = \big(|\vec F_{N(x_2)}|\cdot |x_2| - |\vec F_{N(x_1)} | \cdot |x_1| \big) \hat k$$

We can use a linear system of equations to solve for the normal forces:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\-|x_1|&|x_2| \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} |\vec F_{N(|x_1|)}| \\ |\vec F_{N(|x_2|)}| \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} |m\vec g| \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix} |\vec F_{N(|x_1|)}| \\ |\vec F_{N(|x_2|)}| \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{|x_2|}{|x_1| +|x_2|} & -\frac{1}{|x_1| +|x_2|}\\ \frac{|x_1|}{|x_1| +|x_2|} & \frac{1}{|x_1| +|x_2|} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} |m\vec g| \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{|x_2| \cdot |m\vec g|}{|x_1| +|x_2|} \\ \frac{|x_1|\cdot |m\vec g|}{|x_1| +|x_2|}\end{bmatrix} $$